# Shoopware 6 export sales channel id

Tags: import, export, shopware6

What setting in the export profile do I need to make if I want to make an export from only one specific sales channel?

The column sales_chanel always remains empty and all products from all sales channels are exported. I am getting desperate.

Maybe someone can help me.

Thanks in advance for your help :-)

There seems to be a bug on Shopware's side.